# how constructor injection in spring promotes immutability?

Tags: java, spring

I am new to spring and reading the on line spring reference. One of the advantages of using constructor injection(CI) is because CI is immutable?I know it means that it cannot be modified. But how does that happen, any simple example please to show how CI promote   immutability? thanks

Comment: Passing your initial values into the constructor allows the object to be constructed with those initial values.  Then, you just write the object with getters only, no setters (since you've already set the state through the constructor, there's no need for setters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is an immutable bean, thanking to CI

```
class B1 {
    private final int x;

    B1(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

context.xml

```
<bean id="b1" class="test.B1">
    <constructor-arg value="1"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Ok thanks a lot so since we cannot use final attribute in a setter injection and we can use it with CI, so CI is the injection to use when we need object to be immutable.